# IntelliJ/Android Studio: remove unnecessary use of 'this.'

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, this

I am working on a project where previous developers added lots of `this.x` code which in my opinion makes it longer and thus less readable. And it was placed all over the project by some Eclipse save action.

What I am looking for is an *IntelliJ refactoring* method that I can refactor all self-references on the whole project so that this:

```
this.something = "foo";
```

becomes this:

```
something = "foo";
```

Is there anything like this (I'm using Android Studio 1.2), or do I have to run a regex replace and make sure that nothing breaks?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One way which you can achieve this is by using `Inspections`. You can edit the inspections that are run on your code by going to **Settings** > **Editor** > **Inspections**. The one that you want to change is found within **Java** > **Code Style issues** and it's called **"Unnecessary 'this' qualifier"**.

After checking and applying this inspection it will highlight areas of code which unnecessarily use the `this` keyword. At the moment this won't have any immediate affect on your code base and you would have to go through each instance one by one. In order to fix a batch of inspections warnings then go to **Analyze** > **Inspect code...**

From this option you can choose to run the inspection on specific files or the whole project. This will highlight any instances of code which conflict with your Inspection rules, for example this newly added rule. To apply the fix all you need to do is right click on the issue or group of issues that you wish to fix and then select **Apply fix**.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Text to find "this\."
3. Replace with ""

That should solve your problem.

Comment: That could potentially break code in some places. Let's say if you have `public void setFoo(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }` then search and replace would break it, because in this case `this.` is not unnecessary.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt, yes, you are right. So my answer are not safe.